# D3.js boxplot - turn outliers on/off

Tags: javascript, d3.js, boxplot, outliers

I am using this (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061502) implementation of boxplot in d3.js.

Could someone please help me with implementing a checkbox that would allow me to dynamically turn the graphing of outliers on/off. As a result I would like to see the outliers removed and the y axis adapt itself to show a clearer view of the boxplots. Ideally you can implement this within the `box.js` file from the given implementation by adding a `drawOutliers` parameter.

In the sample below you can see my problem (it sometimes get's so bad you can't even see the boxplots).

My problems are implementing it in JS using d3 and selecting a good way of filtering them out from the data (simply not plotting them or filtering the data, #1 seems better).

[image: graph sample]

Please do not get into discussions as to why it is bad to hide/ignore outliers, etc. I am not ignoring/deleting them, I just need a clearer view of the rest of the graph.

Thank you!

Comment: You can simply set the whiskers to the full range of the data so you don't have any outliers.

Comment: I don't want the graph to include the outlier data. The percentile/median/average/etc values on the graph should remain the same, outliers should not be visible and the boxplot itself should be properly visible.

Comment: I would filter out the outlier values from the data before passing it to the boxplot component instead of modifying the boxplot component to hide some of the data.

Comment: OK, can you suggest an implementation?